# Bash script for Anaconda installer and license agreement

Tags: bash, installation, anaconda

I'm trying to install anaconda in my own docker container with a bash script. The problem is there's a license agreement that you need to hold down a key to agree to, and the length of which depends on your terminal window size. Is there any way to get around this so that I can run `Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh` from start to finish from another bash script?

I tried `echo "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" | ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`, but this only works when the installer asks for an Enter key press the very first time.

Answer (score 9):

```
bash ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p $HOME/anaconda3
```

-b — Batch mode with no PATH modifications to `~/.bashrc`. Assumes that you agree to the license agreement. Does not edit the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files.

-p — Installation prefix/path.

-f — Force installation even if prefix -p already exists.

ref: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/silent-mode/#linux-macos

Comment: -b worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the [yes command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)).

```
yes | ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

As for your question

> What if the last option is asking if I want to install Visual Studio
>   Code, which I'd like to answer no to?

Try this

```
yes no | ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Or replace "no" with whatever you feel is the appropriate response.

Comment: What if the last option is asking if I want to install Visual Studio Code, which I'd like to answer no to?

Comment: So this sorta works, but not exactly. Every 'yes' will go to the next line of the license file, but the number of yes commands required still depends on the size of the terminal window since that determines how many characters per line of the license to show. Therefore I can't simply count how many 'yes' to repeat then determine when to switch to a 'no'.

Comment: Okay, I'm dumb. It took some searching, but it turns out there's just a `-b` argument the install script takes to do this for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've already found the `-b` flag,
but for reference,
here is small, complete scrip
that installs anaconda in `$HOME/anaconda3`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_anaconda_version=2020.02

_anaconda_file="Anaconda3-${_anaconda_version}-Linux-x86_64.sh"

cd
rm -f ${_anaconda_file}*
rm -rf anaconda3/
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/${_anaconda_file}
bash ${_anaconda_file} -b
echo "y" | conda update --all

rm ${_anaconda_file}

unset _anaconda_version _anaconda_file
```